# hover over image is blocking by an element

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have 3 elements that are displayed when hovering on the img element.

[image]

the problem is that when I hover over the icons, hovering over image disrupts and icons start flashing.(hovering happens back and forth between image and icon)

I know that I can add some class like this:

```
.dark-shield {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

to icons, and it fixes it but then I wont be able to apply the click event.
I appreciate if someone can help.

here is my code for display bellow:

```
.invisible {
    visibility: hidden;
}

<div class="container transition-3d-hover ">
    <a href="{% url "gallery-post" post.id %}">
            <img id="{{ post.id }}" class="rounded "
                 src="{{ post.photo.url }}"
                 onmouseenter="f(this)"
                 onmouseleave="f(this)"
            >
    </a>
        <i id="complain-icon-{{ post.id }}"
           class=" fas fa-angry complain-box invisible icon-big dark-shield"></i>
        <i id="fav-icon-{{ post.id }}"
           class=" fa fa-hand-point-up like-box  invisible icon-big "></i>
        <i id="score-icon-{{ post.id }}"
           class=" fas fa-heart fav-box invisible icon-big "></i>

</div>


<script>
 function f(e) {
    var complain = "#" + "complain-icon-" + e.id
    var fav = "#" + "fav-icon-" + e.id
    var score = "#" + "score-icon-" + e.id
    $(complain).toggleClass('invisible')
    $(fav).toggleClass('invisible')
    $(score).toggleClass('invisible')
}

</script>
```

Comment: Have u tried onclick event instead of `<a href `over the img ?? I'm on mobile now can't give u a snippet .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, as you can see, the icons are not a part of the image. So, the icons become invisible when you hover them. After they are invisible, you hover over the image again, and the icon becomes visible. This keeps repeating. So, here is a code snippet that would solve this issue:

```css
.img1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.icon {
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 40%;
  display: none;
}

#wrapper {
  float: left; 
  width: 50%;
  height: 30%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#wrapper:hover .icon {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <img src="https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/wtqqnkYDYi2ifsWZVW2MT4-1200-80.jpg" class="img1">
    <i class="fas fa-angry icon"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-hand-point-up icon" style="top: 20%;"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-heart icon" style="left: 10%; top: 20%;"></i>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Please note:** This code might not work in the snippet, but it would work if you create a new file with this code.

### Code explained

As I have already explained, the icons are not a part of the image. So, when you hover them, they become invisible. However, in my code, I have inserted the images, as well as the icons inside one div. Now, whenever you hover the div, the icons are visible. Since the icons are a part of the same div, they would remain visible.